# What can I do about circuit boards on a new range hood that stopped working in a week or more?

Tags: hood, range

I had my under cabinet wall hood replaced by a hood with chimney. Within a week, the circuit board died. The company sent a replacement hood. The rehab guy didn't replace the hood; just used the new circuit board - which died. A new board was send and the replacement hood was installed using that; lastly longer, about a month then died. The wiring going to the hood was checked, etc. My previous hood, a better one (Dacor) worked fine. The range hood vendor said they have exceeded their obligation and can do no more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this is still under warranty. Contact the manufacturer; the info should be in the user's manual.

Comment: The vendor won't share the manufacturer.

Comment: Who does the owner's manual say to contact for warranty service? Whoever that is owns this problem.